# Check if feature is enabled Oracle 12g 12.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

All,

New to Oracle and am tasked with seeing why a query will not complete in 12c but runs totally fine in 11g. The query will complete in 3-4 minutes on 11g, but will sit and process until you cancel it on 12c.

I'd like to view the features that are enabled, primarily anything dealing with query optimization. How can I do this?

Comment: This kind of thing can happen in any upgrade. I'm not sure comparing the optimizer feature list is going to be that helpful, unless I suppose there were features like cardinality feedback that existed in 11g but that you disabled in the older database.

Comment: One obvious reason for delayed execution of query is `optimizer stats`. Since you recently migrated from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c, might be the case that Optimizer is not having the correct stats and hence not able to generate correct execution plan. On the other hand on Oracle 11g, it had correct stats so it performed well.

Answer (score 2):

youn can take a look at:

- v$ses_optimizer_env
- v$sys_optimizer_env

That said: I would start to take a look at the execution plan: Maybe the difference is not a question of Features, but a result of different statistics in the given Systems.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has an option to emulate optimizer behavior from older versions on the new one. Try to add hint OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('your version of 11g') on 12c, or run this statement within the same session before execution of the query on 12c (assume the version of 11g where query is running fine is 11.2.0.4):

```
ALTER SESSION SET OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE='11.2.0.4';
```